# MongoError: not authorized on (DB name) to execute command

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, express, connect-mongo

I'm using Node.Js, Expressjs, mLab (to host my database) and mongoDB

Im getting an error of not being Authorized on Streetinform(my DB name) to execute command. **{listIndexes: "sessions", cursor: {}}**

this is the error.

[image]

this is how I connect to my Database

```
var dbHost = process.env.DB_HOST || 'localhost';
var dbPort = process.env.DB_PORT ||  3002;
var dbName = process.env.DB_NAME || 'Mongodb';

var dbURL = 'mongodb://'+dbHost+':'+dbPort+'/'+dbName;

if (app.get('env') == 'development'){
// prepend url with authentication credentials // 
    dbURL = 'mongodb://'+process.env.DB_USER+':'+process.env.DB_PASS+'@'+dbHost+':'+dbPort+'/'+dbName;
}

app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    proxy: true,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new MongoStore({ url: dbURL })
    })
);
```

this is my library

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var errorHandler = require('errorhandler');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.load();
var app = express();
```

Establish Connection to Database

```
var crypto      = require('crypto');
var MongoDB     = require('mongodb').Db;
var Server      = require('mongodb').Server;
var moment      = require('moment');

/*
    ESTABLISH DATABASE CONNECTION
*/

var dbName = process.env.DB_NAME || 'mongodb';
var dbHost = process.env.DB_HOST || 'localhost'
var dbPort = process.env.DB_PORT || 3002;

var db = new MongoDB(dbName, new Server(dbHost, dbPort, {autoReconnect: true}), {w: 1});
db.open(function(err, d){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'live') {
            db.authenticate(process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PASS, function(e, res) {
                if (e) {
                    console.log('mongo :: error: not authenticated', e);
                }
                else {
                    console.log('mongo :: authenticated and connected to database :: "'+dbName+'"');
                }
            });
        }   else{
            console.log('mongo :: connected to database :: "'+dbName+'"');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: An obvious question: can you connect to the database with the command line tool and these credential ?

Comment: @Gianluca Yes. I also Updated the Image of the error. and add the Code of establishing database connection

Comment: have you granted the permissions to the user ? See  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I to use mLabs to, it appears that you have not created a database uses due to which it cannot execute any commands.

You can enable it using the following steps:

1. Go to https://mlab.com/home
2. Click on the database which you are using from the Development and Utility
3. Click on the Users tab
4. Click the Add database user button
5. Enter you desired credentials

So now when you are authenticating pass in the username and password that you have entered in step 5